# Perl script: Removing self deplicate rows

Tags: linux, perl, text-processing

I want to process some twitter data sets with a perl script. The file is in a csv format.

I want to remove self addressing mentions

the csv column and data is this way for example

```
user, mention(user), message  
vims789, vnjuei234, yea this is good  
dfion, youwen12, this is win  
don234, don234, this is green   
wen123, tileas, this is blue
```

The duplicate which is `"don234, don234"` mentioning itself, the line should be deleted. Example

user, mention(user), message
vims789, vnjuei234, yea this is good
dfion, youwen12, this is win
wen123, tileas, this is blue

Comment: What have you got so far, and what problem are you having?

Comment: I initially tried trivial  "sort FILE | uniq -c" which gave wrong results;

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Text::CSV;
my $csv = Text::CSV->new();

while ( my $row = $csv->getline( \*DATA ) ) {
    my ( $user, $mention, $message ) = @$row;
    print $message,"\n" unless $user eq $mention;
}
__DATA__
user, mention(user), Message  
vims789, vnjuei234, yea this is good  
dfion, youwen12, this is win  
don234, don234, this is green   
wen123, tileas, this is blue
```

Comment: If this is really the data that the OP has then `Text::CSV` isn't much use because it limits the field separator to a single ASCII character. I recommend `split /\s*,\s*/` as I think it's doubtful that there is always exactly one space after and zero spaces before the comma.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this very quickly with a back-reference. Since you want to find something, a comma, some space, and then that something again, assuming that the string will be all word characters, this should work:

```
my $regex
    = qr{ ^     # beginning of the line
          (\w+) # A "word"
          ,     # A comma
          \s+   # space 
          \1    # a back reference to the first capture.
          \b    # demand that it end the sequence of word characters.
        }x;

my @filtered_lines = grep { !m/$regex/ } @lines;
```